# How to show the full query of a view and query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having issues with a homework assignment where I need to show the full query That the DBMS actually executes.

The view is

```
create view MAJOR_CUSTOMER as
select customer_num, customer_name, balance, credit_limit, rep_num
from customer
where credit_limit < 10001;
```

and the query I used is

```
select customer_name, customer_num
from major_customer
where balance > credit_limit;
```

The big thing I do not understand how to do is to select everything shown in the view and the in another query select and show only customer_name and customer_num.

Comment: don't add where clause, or add with always true condition for example 1=1 ...

Answer (score 0):

Selecting everything in the view can be achieved with

```
SELECT *
FROM major_customer;
```

and as for selecting only customer_name and customer_num, your query you have should work, but to select everything, just remove the where clause:

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_num
FROM major_customer;
```